# Can I install junction box on a basement rim joint from inside

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box, usa

I am pulling wire from my basement for an outside receptacle. I drilled a hole through the rim joist. To secure pvc pipe from inside, I wanted to install a junction box on inside, and use a metal box with middle 1/2 in opening that sits on the joist with the PVC male plug.

Is it OK to have a junction box on rim joist code wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the box on the rim joist as long as it is not covered at a later time the box needs to be accessible.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I am not going to cover it. It will be accessible.